# How to change background colour of an activity via button from another activity

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Im working on a small project with 2 activities. I want to ba able to click a button on one activity and it will change the background colour of all of the activities to #264A73. So far I have;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button about, goDark;
    private RelativeLayout settingsLayout, aboutUs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_settings);

        about=(Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);

        goDark=(Button) findViewById((R.id.dark));

        settingsLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.settingsActivity);

        aboutUs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById((R.id.aboutActivity));

        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        goDark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settingsLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                aboutUs.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });




    }
```

It changes the colour of the current activity (settings) to blue, as I wasn't sure how to use an RGB value there, but gives me a null pointer exception if I try to change the background colour of the AboutUs activity "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference". Any help adding the RGB variable and stopping the null pointer exception would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

the ids I have used, SettingsActivity and AboutActivity are defined as the ids of the relative layouts of the XML files below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settingsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:id="@+id/aboutButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#CACFD9"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topRightRadius="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You use darkness powder"
        android:id="@+id/dark"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:background="#CACFD9"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topRightRadius="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aboutButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aboutActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/rachel_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/piecer"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/thomas_button"
        android:src="@drawable/piecet"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rachel_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rachel_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/hannah_button"
        android:src="@drawable/pieceh"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thomas_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thomas_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/blaine_button"
        android:src="@drawable/pieceb"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hannah_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hannah_button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Rachel Humphrey - Team Leader, part-time sorcerer"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rachel_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Thomas McIlvenna - Programmer, full-time warrior troll"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thomas_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thomas_button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Hannah McClure - Programmer, dwarf extraordinaire"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hannah_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hannah_button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Blaine Crooks - Programmer, bag carrier"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blaine_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/blaine_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach could be to use a static integer in a base Activity class for all the Activities, and in `onResume`, you could update the background color for each Activity.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Integer backgroundColor;

    @Override
    public void onResume {
        super.onResume();

        upgradeBackgroundColor();
    }

    public void updateBackgroundColor() {
        if(backgroundColor != null) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        }
    }
    public void changeAppBackground(int color) {
        backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

You would have your settings activity call `changeAppBackground` with the new color to change the color on all the Activities.

A more sophisticated approach would be to have multiple themes in your `styles.xml` file, and have all the activities either update their themes in `onResume`, or via a listener (if necessary).

To update the theme, you would use the same approach, a base activity with a static integer for the theme, and you would call `setTheme(theme)` in `onResume`.

You can have a theme define a background using the `android:windowBackground` property, e.g.:

```
<style name="MyWhiteTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyBlackTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: so within my settings file would I have it extend BaseActivity and  just call settingsLayout.changeAppBackground(#264A73);  within my OnClickListener?

Comment: In the OnClickListener, you would need to call `changeAppBackground(0xff264a73); updateBackgroundColor();`

Comment: You are an absolute legend my friend, been working on that for hours haha, thank you very much